# Django rest framework jwt {"detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."}

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am trying to make a request using django-rest-framework and [django-rest-framework-jwt](https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/) but The response that I get `detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."`

**views.py**

```
class Test(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = []
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    def get(self, request):
        return response.Response({"test": "Test "}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**urls.py**

```
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token, refresh_jwt_token
from .views import Test
urlpatterns = [
    path('', Test.as_view(), name='test'),
    path('token/', obtain_jwt_token, name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', refresh_jwt_token, name='token_refresh'),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',
    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',
    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PUBLIC_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PRIVATE_KEY': None,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_LEEWAY': 0,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': timedelta(days=5),
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': None,
    'JWT_ISSUER': None,
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': timedelta(days=7),
    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,
}
```

and the request that I made:
`>curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/ -H 'Authorization: Token eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMCwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJoYXNhbm1iaWxhbDE5OThAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNjUxNTkxMDYxLCJlbWFpbCI6Imhhc2FubWJpbGFsMTk5OEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJvcmlnX2lhdCI6MTY1MTE1OTA2MX0.bvmtH6mnItBjwKkvaNU5eMXlEyk2ZAytMWzhEE_Ibhs'`

**Note:** I've used [django-rest-framework-simplejwt](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and got the same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You've set your `authentication_classes=[]`, so auth is not run for this view
2. You then require they are logged in with your `permissions_classes`

For now just remove the `authentication_classes = []` from the view.  Your default permissions also require authentication, so that line could also be removed.

Based on your usage here you should probably use `APIView` rather than the generics.  If you plan to use the features of the generics (and construct the routes correctly manually) then keep at it.

```
class Test(APIView):
    # use default permission_classes in REST_FRAMEWORK
    # use default authentication_classes in REST_FRAMEWORK

    def get(self, request):
        return Response({"data": "Test"})
```

To answer your new question, and after [referring to the documentation](https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/) for the `rest_framework_jwt` package, you need to send the token as `Authorization: JWT {token}`.

[image]

If this isn't the right documentation or package, please send a link to the correct one along with the location that says to use `Token` (which is actually how simple_jwt works, not this package).

In your settings file you actually override *all* the default settings, when you only need the ones you want to change.  In this list, at the bottom, I see this:

```
    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
```

Comment: I made the code like your, but it get me `"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."`

Comment: Also I forgot to notice, I am using a custom User model.

Comment: Which user model doesn't matter.  I've updated the answer and linked to the docs.